# docker postgres container not starting

Tags: postgresql, docker

Initial state:

```
$ docker image ls -a | grep postgres
# no entries

$ docker container ls -a | grep postgres
# no entries
```

After pulling & starting postgres:

```
$ docker pull postgres
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/postgres
bd159e379b3b: Pulling fs layer
...
c37cbd0077ed: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:769422529210357f359e7e5620246028837f84fabe92c838ca2aef75fe2e0741
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:latest
docker.io/library/postgres:latest
```

start:

```
$ docker run -itd -e POSTGRES_USER=sebi -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=******* -p 5432:5432 -v "C:\Work\postgres":/var/lib/postgresql/data --name postgresql postgres
41d99a1636f9b53ea45f1f90f979b59779fca0a6c42e4f12d84ca430d160b084
```

The container, however, is not started:

```
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND            CREATED      STATUS       PORTS                           NAMES
92b67a93a739   dpage/pgadmin4   "/entrypoint.sh"   2 days ago   Up 2 hours   443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5051->80/tcp   pgadmin-awesome-links
```

but it has been created:

```
$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS                                                                                                                                  NAMES
41d99a1636f9   postgres                              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 minutes ago   Exited (1) 10 minutes ago                                                                                                                                          postgresql
92b67a93a739   dpage/pgadmin4                        "/entrypoint.sh"         2 days ago       Up 2 hours                  443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5051->80/tcp                                                                                                          pgadmin-proto
```

Why isn't the container started?

**Edit #1:**

logs look alright:

```
$ docker logs postgresql
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
initdb: hint: You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start

waiting for server to start....2022-10-16 22:57:48.906 UTC [49] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.0 (Debian 15.0-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2022-10-16 22:57:48.939 UTC [49] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-10-16 22:57:49.013 UTC [52] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-10-16 22:57:45 UTC
2022-10-16 22:57:49.076 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started
CREATE DATABASE


/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

2022-10-16 22:57:51.065 UTC [49] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
waiting for server to shut down....2022-10-16 22:57:51.074 UTC [49] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2022-10-16 22:57:51.077 UTC [49] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 55) exited with exit code 1
2022-10-16 22:57:51.077 UTC [50] LOG:  shutting down
2022-10-16 22:57:51.085 UTC [50] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2022-10-16 22:57:52.003 UTC [50] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 918 buffers (5.6%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.326 s, sync=0.538 s, total=0.926 s; sync files=250, longest=0.006 s, average=0.003 s; distance=4217 kB, estimate=4217 kB
2022-10-16 22:57:52.106 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2022-10-16 22:57:52.171 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.0 (Debian 15.0-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2022-10-16 22:57:52.171 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-10-16 22:57:52.171 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-10-16 22:57:52.179 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-10-16 22:57:52.203 UTC [64] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-10-16 22:57:51 UTC
2022-10-16 22:57:52.237 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2022-10-16 23:02:52.303 UTC [62] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2022-10-16 23:02:56.345 UTC [62] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 42 buffers (0.3%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=3.969 s, sync=0.025 s, total=4.043 s; sync files=12, longest=0.004 s, average=0.003 s; distance=241 kB, estimate=241 kB
```

For some reason it started working ...

**Edit #2:**

Renaming doesn't seem to work; pulling a specific postgres docker image:

$ docker pull postgres:14.2
14.2: Pulling from library/postgres
214ca5fb9032: Pulling fs layer
...
Digest: sha256:2c954f8c5d03da58f8b82645b783b56c1135df17e650b186b296fa1bb71f9cfd
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:14.2
docker.io/library/postgres:14.2

then renaming the image:

```
$ docker image tag 9dbc24674f25 postgres-proto/postgres:14.2
```

produces:

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY                                                                   TAG                                                                        IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
dpage/pgadmin4                                                               latest                                                                     94c0924749b6   3 weeks ago     366MB
postgres                                                                     14.2                                                                       9dbc24674f25   5 months ago    376MB
postgres-proto/postgres                                              14.2                                                                       9dbc24674f25   5 months ago    376MB
```

The previous image name cannot be deleted:

```
$ docker rmi postgres
Error: No such image: postgres
```

by id:

```
$ docker rmi 9dbc24674f25
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 9dbc24674f25 (must be forced) - image is referenced in multiple repositories
```

Comment: Check the logs using `docker logs postgresql`. It probably fails during startup and the logs will tell you more about why.

Comment: @HansKilian updated; seems to be working now.